# Change Solr Field type

Tags: solr

One string field in Lucene/Solr is stored like this: 'yyyyMMdd'.
I need to convert the field to tdate type.

How can I achieve this and do a re-index?

Comment: You can chnage the type of your field in schema.xml to tdate and then re-index it.

Comment: how do you do that if I also need to convert the date to an appropriate format?

Comment: are you using DIH for indexing?...if yes then you can add the datetimeformat in the entity where you mention the field

Comment: so I should copy the lucene core in another place and use it as a source with DIH?

Comment: yes by modifying the entity field in your data-config.xml and add the attribute dateTimeFormat="dd/mm/yyyy" and mention the format you want

Answer (score 0):

If your data is coming with the incomplete date format and you want to parse it, you need to use UpdateRequestProcessor chain for that. The specific URP is [ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory](http://www.solr-start.com/info/update-request-processors/#ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory). It's used as part of schemaless example in Solr, so you can check its usage in the solrconfig.xml there.

Most likely, you need to re-index from the source collection. There is no rewrite in-place options in Solr for individual fields.